# Keeping Aspect Ration of ImageButton in AppWidget on Resizing

Tags: android, android-widget, scaling, aspect-ratio, remoteview

I've got an ImageButton in my homescreen widget.
It is supposed to get larger/smaller when the user resizes the widget but stay perfectly round.

The following code seems works to work on the emulator but on some phones the circle is still oval (maybe 10% higher than wide).
I'm using padding because i have not found a way to set the size of a remote view in code.
Thank you.

AppWidgetProvider:

```
@Override
public void onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId, Bundle newOptions) {
...
onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, new int[]{appWidgetId});
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

Bundle options = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetOptions(myIds[id]);
                    int minWidth = options.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_WIDTH);
                    int minHeight = options.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_HEIGHT);

                    int width = Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, minWidth, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
                    int height = Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, minHeight, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));

                    views.setViewPadding(R.id.image_button,0, (height-width)/2,0,(height-width)/2);
...
```

widget.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llWidget"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/widget_button"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="@drawable/widget_button"
        android:elevation="2dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

widget_button.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
        </shape>
    </item>

</ripple>
```

Comment: use the ring shape instead of oval

Comment: @Zahoor Saleem How does that change the scaling? Do i have to use some special attributes or something?

Comment: <shape android:shape="oval"> change it to <shape android:shape="ring"> it will solve you error

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I used the following attributes to keep the middle of the ring filled. <shape
            android:shape="ring"
            android:useLevel="false"
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:thicknessRatio="2">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
</shape>